# How to prevent duplicate value in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I want to restrict duplicate value, How could I do.

```php
if($_GET["data"] == "add_class"){

            $name = $_POST["txtName"];
            $sql = "Insert into tbl_class (class_name) values (:class_name);";
            $insert = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $insert->bindParam(':class_name', $name);

            if($insert->execute()){
                   echo json_encode("Insert Success");}
            else{ 
                   echo json_encode("Insert Faild");}    
    }
```

Comment: Just add a unique index on `class_name`

Comment: could you help me?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tbl_class ADD UNIQUE KEY (class_name)` for MySQL...

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not really sure how to implement that.

Comment: It's a query you need to execute. Once you do, any attempt to insert a duplicate `class_name` value will fail.

Comment: @Veasna Run that command in the DB where you are using it and that column in `tbl_class` table will be unique. Run once.